# Integration, of $x^a$ where $a$ is an irrational number.

Tags: calculus, integration

Can we integrate $x^{\sqrt{2}}$, or one can integrate $x^q$ only when q is some rational number. Integration of $x^q$ is $(x^{q+1})/(q+1)$.

Comment: The same rules apply whatever $q$ could be (even a complex number).

Comment: Hint: Can you derive $x^q$ when $q$ is irrational ? If yes, the integral is nothing but an antiderivative...

Comment: It turns out that the derivative of $x^\alpha=\alpha x^{\alpha-1}$ even when $\alpha$ is irrational.

Comment: I think you could do it by showing that if $\frac{P_n}{Q_n}\to\alpha$, then $x^{P_n/Q_n}\to x^\alpha$ and $(x^{P_n/Q_n})^\prime\to(x^\alpha)^\prime$. (Which would mean that $\frac{P_n}{Q_n}x^{P_n/Q_n-1})\to(x^\alpha)^\prime$, which would mean that $\alpha x^{\alpha-1}=(x^\alpha)^\prime$.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The rule $\int x^n \ dx = \frac{1}{n+1}x^{n+1}+C$ holds for all real $n \neq -1$.

Comment: And the rule that $\int x^ndx=\frac1{n+1}x^{n+1}-\frac1{n+1}+C$ works for _all_ reals, assuming you extend it by continuity for $n=-1$.

Answer (score 1):

We define $x^n=e^{n\ln x}$ for $n\not\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Now

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dx}(x^n)&=\frac{d}{dx}(e^{n\ln x})
\\&=e^{n\ln x}\cdot n\cdot \frac{1}{x}
\\&=n\cdot\frac{e^{n\ln x}}{x}
\\&=n\cdot \frac{e^{n\ln x}}{e^{\ln x}}
\\&=n\cdot e^{n\ln x-\ln x}
\\&=n\cdot e^{(n-1)\ln x}
\\&=n\cdot x^{n-1}.
\end{align}$$

Therefore if $n\neq 1$ we have

$$\int x^n\,dx=\frac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C.$$

Comment: I wonder if you could use the alternate definition for $x^\alpha,\alpha\not\in\Bbb Q$: if $\frac{P_n}{Q_n}\to\alpha$, then $x^{P_n/Q_n}\to x^\alpha$. I'm hoping that one could then prove that $(x^{P_n/Q_n})^\prime\to(x^\alpha)^\prime$. (Which, if true, would mean that $\frac{P_n}{Q_n}x^{P_n/Q_n-1})\to(x^\alpha)^\prime$, which would mean that $\alpha x^{\alpha-1}=(x^\alpha)^\prime$.)

Answer (score 1):

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\left\{-1\right\}: \int x^n\ dx=\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1}+C$$
Hence:
$$\int x^{\sqrt{2}}\ dx=\dfrac{x^{\sqrt{2}+1}}{\sqrt{2}+1}+C$$